# How can i generate the access token for aiesec API

Tags: java, android, json

I want to use the aiesec api in an android application but i can't generate the token to use the API 
the link of the api : https://gis-api.aiesec.org/swagger#/

Comment: Still relevant question

Answer (score 0):

1. Open experience.aiesec.org
2. Inspect element
3. Input your email and your password
4. Choose network menu in inspect element
5. Choose all menu
6. And input in filter seach "token"
7. You will get your access token for  https://gis-api.aiesec.org/swagger#/

Answer (score 0):

From what I found you can send the request to https://auth.aiesec.org/users/sign_in with your usual email and password, get response, and from that you can parse cookies to get `expa_token`, which is the access token for the API.

I'm not sure if there are other methods how to get this token, but it works.